# How to add Formik in Storybook with MDX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, storybook

I am trying to add an Input story in Storybook.

This story is an input field, so it uses Formik's `<Field/>` tag.

However, when I try to view the story in the browser, nothing appears.

I've added the `'storybook-formik/register'` in `.storybook/main.js`, but nothing changes.

This is my code:

```js
// Input.js
import React from 'react'
import {Field} from 'formik'

export default function Input({type, name, placeholder, dataId}) {
  return (
    <Field
      type={type}
      name={name}
    />
  )
}
```

```js
// Input.stories.mdx
import Input from './Input'
import {Canvas, Meta, Story} from '@storybook/addon-docs'

<Meta title="forms/Input" component={Input} />

export const Template = (args) => <Input {...args} />

# An input box

<Canvas>
  <Story
    name="input-box"
    args={{
      type: 'text',
      name: 'Email',
    }}>
    >{Template.bind({})}
  </Story>
</Canvas>
```